# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el marcador de posición de decimales ("%.2f") aleatorio?

Tags: python, random

Me surgió un problema y por ende una duda acerca del marcador de posición de decimales, ya que al intentar modificar el entero `"%.2f"` por `"%.(entero)f"` me arrojaba la consola el error `ValueError: Format specifier missing precision`

Fragmento de mi código:

```
from random import randint, randrange, choice, uniform
g1,g2,g3=randint(2,3), randrange(2,3), randrange(2,3)
for i in range(3):
    x1,y1,z1=('{0:.(g1)f}'.format(x), '{0:.(g2)f}'.format(y), '{0:.(g3)f}'.format(z))
```

Hay alguna forma de corregir este problema. Agradezco mucho su apoyo.

Comment: Cambia, por ejemplo, `'{0:.(g1)f}'.format(x)` cambialo a `'{0:.{g1}f}'.format(x, g1=randint(2,3))`. De esa manera le indicas a Python que vas a ingresar un valor que le pasas por el comando `format`.

Comment: También es valido `'{0:.{}f}'.format(x, randint(2,3))`

Comment: Excelente, funcionó. Muchas gracias amigo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar f-strings, que es lo más versátil y fácil de usar.

Un f-string es una letra "f" seguida de una cadena, como

```
print(f"El valor es {x}")
```

Lo especial es que si encierras algo entre corchetes, Python lo interpreta como una expresión, que es evaluada y sustituida dentro de la cadena.

En este ejemplo, si `x = 10.12`, entonces

```
print(f"El valor es {x}") -> El valor es 10.12
```

Si quieres formatear también la variable, agregas el formato separado por ":", asi:

```
print(f"El valor es {x:.1f}") -> El valor es 10.1
```

Ahora, quieres que el número de decimales sea variable, puedes reemplazar el `:.1f` por `:.{n}f`, quedando así:

```
valor = 12.3456
for n in range(4):
    print(f"{valor:.{n}f}")
```

produce:

```
12
12.3
12.35
12.346
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque no intento hacer un bucle definido para imprimir la posición de los decimales, es bueno hacer retroalimentación sobre el tema. Saludos!

Comment: @UlisesAntonioChávez. El `for` es sólo para demostrar que la solución funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es manejar el numero de decimales puedes usar:

```
round(12.345, n)
```

Donde *n* es el numero de decimales que quieras.

Algo así entiendo:

```py
from random import randint, randrange

g1,g2,g3=randint(2,3), randrange(2,3), randrange(2,3)

for i in range(3):
    x1,y1,z1 =(round(i, g1), round(i, g2), round(i, g3))
```

Comment: `print(round(12.000, 3)) -> 12.0` La función `round` transforma el valor, no su representación.